How to heterodyne two signals?
Is there a way I can get two different simultaneously transmitted signal to heterodyne?
I know how to use a mixer to cause it to heterodyne but what I need is to transmit the two signal and with a receiver get back the heterodyned signals.
Example:
Two signals 20k Hz and 21K Hz transmitted.
Receiver is for 1k Hz.
1k Hz filter has been tested using the signals with a mixer and works great.
The reason:
It is said that there is a lithostatic field that surrounds a void that causes rf signals to heterodyne.
I'd like to test my transmitters and receiver but I don't have a void in my back yard.

As long as there is sufficient separation between the signals, you can square the combined signal and the two signals will heterodyne.
Below is a simple demonstration of this for two tones where the sum signal is squared. The upper plot is the spectrum of the summed signal and the lower plot is the resulting spectrum of the squared signal, where we see all the sum and difference products that result

And below is the case of squaring the sum of a modulated passband waveform with a tone (similar to multiplying a modulated passband waveform with a single tone from a local oscillator for a down-converter application). Notice that we get the sum and difference of the waveform with the tone as desired, but we also get other intermodulation products from the square of the waveform itself (that is a copy of the modulated waveform with it's bandwidth doubled), restricting the available range of frequencies between the signals for which we can do a non-linearity in place of a mixer.

Passing the summed signal through any non-linearity will also result in heterodyning (as well as many other frequency products).
In analog hardware, a Schottky diode is such a device that can be used for this purpose. In fact there are single diode mixers constructed based on this principal where the shunt diode in interfaced to matching networks and filters for signals of interest.
How this works can be understood by taking the non-linear equation for the IV curve of a diode and expanding it into its Taylor series components, where you will see the amount that is part of the square law ($x^2$) relationship for the signal. This is the one that provides the sum and difference terms between input frequencies as can be seen in the cosine or sine product rule:
$$\cos(\omega_1 t)\cos(\omega_2 t) = \frac{1}{2}\cos((\omega_1 + \omega_2)) +  \frac{1}{2}\cos((\omega_1 - \omega_2))$$
Of course the non-linear device has many higher order products to different weights (as determined by the Taylor series directly) which results in many other factors call "intermodulation products" or for brevity: "intermods". For two sinusoids at frequency $f_1$ and $f_2$, all the intermods will be at frequencies $mf_1 \pm nf_2$ for integers $m, n$.  If the individual waveforms are not single tones but have bandwidth, then the individual frequency components within each waveform will also have intermodulation products that will land in band (degrading SNR) or adjacent to the signal (degrading out-of-band emissions if transmitted or adjacent channels if received). All analog hardware will have some level of non-linearity (due to compression), and so these products will always exist (but if our device is linear enough, they will be well below the noise floor or level of concern).
